# Android Release version cannot connect to server

Tags: android, cordova

We have a cordova app that is working fine on ios, and the debug build for Android works fine. The problem is when we build a release version. The app will start up, but none of the ajax calls work.

We've tried a lot of things. We have updated cordova, we have changed the config.xml to have:

```
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

The only thing that has worked so far is changing the release apk's AndroidManifest.xml to debuggable. We did this so we could debug the problem, but it actually made it so that the ajax calls were being made. I tried uploading that APK, but Google play won't accept an apk that is debuggable.

sigh.....

One other thing that could be helpful information is we recently had to change the Domain of our server. We edited all the files to point to the appropriate server. So they are pointing to the correct host, but I figured it could possibly be a problem with certificates or CORS even.

We could really use some help if anybody has any ideas.

Comment: What does the network/console say about those network requests?

Comment: So because it's the release apk we can't see anything from the console. That's why we thought to change the Android manifest to debuggable to see what the network/console says, but since changing it to debuggable fixed the issue we weren't able to get any useful information.

Comment: Oh duh, my bad.  Stupid question on my part.  Do you have the ability to see if any of the requests are going through from the server side?  I.e. if you are making an api request to your server you can see if the request is going through on that side.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I'll give it a try. Is there anything in particular that you are looking for in the requests?

Comment: I've checked the server request logs, and it's not logging to either the access logs nor the error logs.

Comment: That lets you know the issue is something on the app side.  I haven't come across an issue like yours that isn't related to the whitelist plugin, wish I could give further guidance but I'm stumped at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me and my co worker had a very similar issue to this, we tried everything that was said in these answers and nothing worked. We finally found our issue was an ssl certificate issue with cordova. It is an awful issue because it never exactly tells you its an issue.
here is a link of the article that helped us the most:

http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/

really hope this helps!

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the solution here, as this answer might get useless if the linked page changes or vanishes

Comment: I am so happy this helped!!

Answer (score 0):

The most common issue with this type of error is that the app is missing the whitelist plugin.  It is necessary for Android apps, but not for iOS apps.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

Then in your config.xml you can add the following to allow everything:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="itms:*" />
<allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: We've got the plugin added and we've got all the allow-intent. We have got the access origin as well.

Answer (score 0):

The linked solution still works for Cordova 9. As I can't comment on answers yet, I write the relevant parts here as Nico wished in case the link doesn't work anymore at some point:

Cordova on Android platforms allows invalid certificates, but only in build mode, and not in release mode, because the WebView doesn't allow "insecure" requests. You have to change 3 lines in the original platform code from Cordova in the following function:

```
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
  final String packageName = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName();
  final PackageManager pm = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();

  ApplicationInfo appInfo;
  try {
    appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
      // debug = true
      handler.proceed();
      return;
    } else {
      // debug = false
      // THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED TO CHANGE:
      // 1. COMMENT THIS LINE
      // super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
      // 2. ADD THESE TWO LINES
      // ---->
      handler.proceed();
      return;
      // <----
    }
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // When it doubt, lock it out!
    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
  }
}
```

The file containing the function is SystemWebViewClient.java for Cordova Version 5 and above. In previous versions it's CordovaWebViewClient.java.

Paths:
V5+: project/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewClient.java
V4-: project/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java

Source: Content from [link mentionend above by Nico Haase and written by JC Ivancevich](http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/)